# Is it possible to intelligently profile Windows slow boot?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, performance

My Windows boots very slow. If include time when it apparently booted, but applications are still freezing (i.e. impossible to work), the boot time is more than 20 minutes.

Hardware configuration can't be a reason except I am not usind SSD.

Is it possible to completely measure boot time and pinpoint the slowing reasons? I don't want to use brute-force approach of uninstalling and installing applications.

Answer (score 1):

To determinate what could it be the reason to the slow boot up of your OS once you access to your profile open task manager in the process tab and see which column show out with more percentage of usage, probably it is the disk access; If I understand good you do not have an SSD disk. Based on the expirience I had with windows OS on mechanical disks principally there have two main reason the computer slow down really a lot:

- Antivirus software

  - it get high priority to update virus database
- Windows search indexes

  - Indexing of files to use the search feature get a high priority to the disk and need really long time to terminate successfully

What I says above is the common situation I encountered, that does not mean are the same for you. I find this blog on technet which describe how to measure the reboot cycle with sysinternals tools: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/robertsmith/2017/07/19/an-easy-way-to-measure-computer-reboot-and-logon-times/